# jquery dropdown list detect if default value selected

Tags: jquery

How can I detect in jquery if default value of dropdown list is selected? The below code is triggered only if I change the previously selected value. If I do not change the value (I reselect the same value) the code is not triggered.

```
$('select[name="spinner-name"]').change(function(){ ... });
```

Comment: What makes sense, since there is no change. So why do you need the trigger if the User does not do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no change-event fired if there was no actual change in selection, but you can mimic the behavior from checking the current value from click-handler (as you are clicking on the dropdown when you "select" the previous value again).

```js
    $("select").on({        
        "click": function() {
            alert('selected: '+$(this).val());
        },
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```